# How to get all elements in collection when building an array of items?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code which works great returns a `XElement` object from instance properties on the class:

```
public MyClass1 MyClass1 {get; set;}
public MyClass2 MyClass2 {get; set;}

var elements = new[]
{
   //Calls to .GetXML() return an XElement instance
   this.MyClass1.GetXML(),
   this.MyClass2.GetXML()
};

return new XElement("Root",
    elements.Where(el => el != null && !el.IsEmpty));
```

Problem is I want to introduce a collection via `IList` for say `MyClass3` and have no idea on how to get all of the items in the collection into my `elements` array. So I want the following now:

```
public MyClass1 MyClass1 {get; set;}
public MyClass2 MyClass2 {get; set;}
public IList<MyClass3> MyClass3 {get; set;}

var elements = new[]
{
   this.MyClass1.GetXML(),
   this.MyClass2.GetXML(),
   this.MyClass3.ToList().Select(x => x.GetXML())  //Not working
};
```

I have tried using combinations of `Select` and even changed `IList` into `List` just to see if `.ForEach` would work and that didn't either. The error I'm getting is: *"No best type found for implicitly typed array"* regardless of the method I try.

How can I get all of the elements from my `IList` property instance into the `elements` array? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:** Order *must* be preserved (i.e. MyClass1, MyClass2, MyClass3), so If I introduce another element `MyClass4` it must come after `MyClass3`. The reasoning is because I'm composing a XML document with a specific structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want something like:

```
var elements = new[] { MyClass1.GetXML(), MyClass2.GetXML() }
      .Concat(MyClass3.Select(x => x.GetXML())
      .ToArray();
```

With MyClass4 after MyClass3:

```
var elements = new[] { MyClass1.GetXML(), MyClass2.GetXML() }
      .Concat(MyClass3.Select(x => x.GetXML())
      .Concat(new[] { MyClass4.GetXML() })
      .ToArray();
```

Or putting the `GetXML` in one place:

```
// Relies on covariance in .NET 4
var elements = new MyBase[] { MyClass1, MyClass2 }
    .Concat(MyClass3)
    .Concat(new[] { MyClass4 })
    .Select(x => x.GetXML())
    .ToArray();
```

Or without using LINQ at all until the end:

```
var items = new List<BaseClass>();
items.Add(MyClass1);
items.Add(MyClass2);
items.AddRange(MyClass3);
items.Add(MyClass4);
var elemets = items.Select(x => x.GetXML()).ToArray();
```

Comment: I should of mentioned (edited OP) since I'm composing XML, order matters. What if I introduce `MyClass4` and `MyClass3` had to come come before in order? If I use `.Concat` the `MyClass4` if placed in the original array grouping would come before `MyClass3`. Is there a way to make sure ordering is preserved?

Comment: @atconway: In that case you'd need another `Concat` with another array *after* the `Concat` with `MyClass3`. Of course another option is not to use LINQ at all: just create a `List<XElement>` and call either `Add` or `AddRange` for each item you want.

Comment: Interesting but not sure how I'd do it. My `GetXML` method is defined on a base class dictating a return type of `XElement` so I can't change return type `List<XElement>` instead. Also I don't have to use LINQ so if there is any other method I'm open to that as well.

Comment: @atconway: I've added a few more options :)

Comment: Thank you, I like the last option best. Is there any performance advantage over any of the options or are they all really the same? Wondered about last option since it's building a collection of classes, and didn't know if there is any performance hit against this or are my thoughts unfounded?

Comment: @atconway: You're *almost certainly* worrying about the wrong thing. I would be astonished if this became a significant performance hit. Write the cleanest code you can, and then *measure* whether it's fast enough when you've got a meaningful scenario.

Comment: 10-4 that's what I wanted to know. Just trying to learn. Thank you.